# Can I do an IF statement / Ternary Operator within an <img src' ' >?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Okay, I know this might seem a little off but I am trying to achieve a solution where an image URL is used only when the image URL is valid and exists.

```
$imglink = URL . 'public/uploads/profile/' . $value['image'];  //valid to be used if image exists
$defaultLink = URL . 'public/images/profile-img.jpg';   // To be used if $imglink is not available
```

What I have tried is:

```
$loki = $imglink ? $imglink : $defaultLink;

$imageURL = "<img src='$loki'  width='120px' height='120px' style='border-radius: 50%; border: 2px solid #edf9f3'/>";
```

ALSO Tried this:

```
$imageURL = "<img src='<?php echo $imglink ? $imglink : $defaultLink />'  width='120px' height='120px' style='border-radius: 50%; border: 2px solid #edf9f3'/>";
```

I have tried using different approaches but it isn't working. Also, this is being done in a Codeigniter Controller file.

Comment: No, you can not use `if` inside of a _string_. And no, you can not use `<?php … ?>` again _inside_ of a string either. You could do this in several steps - assign first part of the string, then do an actual if/else, where you append more to the end of your string variable, and then the rest after; or you can use the _ternary operator_ directly inside a string concatenation statement.

Comment: I might not have clearly stated what isn't working. Well, the statement is not executed within the <img src=' ' />

Comment: @CBroe I appreciate the idea, however, can you give me an example with the ternary and string concatenation?

Comment: Please do a minimum of research on your own. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165265/ternary-operator-inside-php-string/14165313, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506527/how-do-i-use-the-ternary-operator-in-php-as-a-shorthand-for-if-else

Comment: @Astrildz Your 2nd snippet should work, given `$imglink` and `$defaultLink` actually contain what you think they do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first check the value in ternary operator and then assign it properly-

```
// check if $value['image'] is set and not empty; assign value accordingly.
$img = ( !empty($value['image']) ) ? ( URL . 'public/uploads/profile/' . $value['image'] ) : ( URL . 'public/images/profile-img.jpg' );

// give that value in src of img tag
$imageURL = "<img src='" .$img. "'  width='120px' height='120px' style='border-radius: 50%; border: 2px solid #edf9f3'/>";
```

See if it helps you. :)

Comment: You don't need both `isset()` and `!empty()`. Just using the `empty()` function is enough. - Not my downvote btw.