# ternary operator in array

Tags: php

I am trying to use the ternary operator in a string in PHP

```
"hard_copy"=>"<input type='checkbox' (($station->hard_copy==1)?'checked':'') name='station[]' id='hard-copy-$key' class='hard-copy' value='hardcopy-$station->id-1' >
<label for='hard-copy-$key' style='margin-left: 30%;'></label>",
```

but I am having probably some syntax error

Comment: can you include the error

Comment: there is no error i am trying to check the checkbox upon condition and checkbox is not getting checked

Comment: You can't unpack statements inside double quoted strings like that, only variables. You need to use concatenation. `"foo " . ($a == 1 ? 'checked' : '') . " bar"`

Comment: you're using these in a blade file right?

Comment: its in controller

Comment: can u show me your controller class ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ternary Operator Inside PHP String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165265/ternary-operator-inside-php-string)

Comment: If you get an error, always include the error in your question.

Comment: how can i show the whole class?

Comment: You don't need to show your whole class. Your issue has already been answered, both in comments and as real answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I Will answer as I understand the question**

as @Magnus Eriksson mentioned " You can't unpack statements inside double-quoted strings like that, only variables. You need to use concatenation. "

try this one

```
"hard_copy"=>
"<input type='checkbox' ". (($station->hard_copy==1) ? 'checked' : '') . "name='station[]' id='hard-copy-$key' class='hard-copy' value='hardcopy-$station->id-1' >
<label for='hard-copy-'".$key." style='margin-left: 30%;'></label>",
```

Comment: Good, but please explain what you've changed, so he can learn from your answer.

Comment: can you explain why we had to use concatenation for this purpose?

Comment: as @Magnus Eriksson mentioned " You can't unpack statements inside double-quoted strings like that, only variables. You need to use concatenation. "

Answer (score 0):

Try this using concatenation:

```
"hard_copy"=> "<input type='checkbox' ". ($station->hard_copy==1 ? 'checked':'' )." name='station[]' id='hard-copy-".$key."' class='hard-copy' value='hardcopy-".$station->id."-1' ><label for='hard-copy-".$key."' style='margin-left: 30%;'></label>",
```

Comment: You also need to add parentheses around the statement: `" . ($station->hard_copy == 1 ? 'checked' : '') . "`.